# IPFS Versioning for dynamic content

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, storage, ipfs

is it possible to keep versioning in IPFS?

Like im saving one row of record like

```
pid:1, mid:3, status: started --> v1

pid:1, mid:3 status;completed --> v1.1
```

is there any way to implement this in IPFS or swarm or any decentralised data storage?

is it possible to acheive versioning by the help of IPNS?

Regards
Mani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user could keep its own version of the data. If you want a public state of the dapp, then you probably want to go to a public blockchain like Ethereum.

Updating a lot of data can be expansive, however you can create a signature of data, as merkle root or hash, and store that inchain, and post the contents in a decentralized storage like IPFS.

For versioning, ENS might be useful, as you could keep the latest resolving under `yourapp.eth`, and the versions on subdomains like `v1.yourapp.eth`.